# Connect to .db file using Mule ESB or java

Tags: java, database, mule

I have an application that generates a .db file and then I have to use that .db file as database. Is there some way to use this .db file in Mule ESB or java?

Please Help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which is the format of this .db file?

Comment: The question is not coherent with the title. Do you want to use it with or without Java?

Comment: Shouldn't the question title be something like "Reading a .db file with Mule ESB or Java"...?

Comment: Do you want to use .db file as a database and want to create connection to it? Do you have driver jar for it? If both answer are YES, then you can create DB connection using `Database connector` with `Generic Database configuration`.

Comment: The .db file is created by Sybase. And I have to use that .db file as database. @ericbn

Comment: @VijayPande answer for first is yes , but I don't have driver jar for it. And I'm not familiar with Sybase. so have no clue how to do it